# Iterate dictionary in dictionary

Tags: ansible

I have a json structure like this:

```
{
  "group_a": {
    "setting_one": "text one",
    "setting_two": "text two"
  },
  "group_b": {
    "setting_three": "text three",
    "setting_four": "text four"
  }
}
```

And I need to do iterate over the dicts inside the dicts and create tasks,  kinda like this:

```
- name: Task group_a setting_one
  ...
- name: Task group_a setting_two
  ...
- name: Task group_b setting_three
  ...
- name: Task group_b setting_four
  ...
```

I was hoping to make something like this:

```
- name: Insert {{ group }} {{ setting }}
  ini_file:
    path: settings.ini
    section: "{{ group }}"
    option: "{{ setting }}"
    value: "{{ setting_value }}"
  with_nested:
    - "{{ data.keys() }}" # Can I get this key and use in the next loop?
    - "{{ data.key.keys() }}"
```

How can I do this? I have been messing about with `loop`, `with_items`, `with_dict` etc, but I can't manage to get it exactly the way I need. I also tried `with_nested`, but that does not seem to do what I need either.

Kind regards, Jonas

Answer (score 0):

Let's reduce the structure to one with the same piece of information

```
my_data:
  group_a:
    - one
    - two
  group_b:
    - three
    - four
```

Then the play below

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.0.key }} setting_{{ item.1 }}"
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ my_data|dict2items }}"
    - value
```

gives:

```
"msg": "group_b setting_three"
"msg": "group_b setting_four"
"msg": "group_a setting_one"
"msg": "group_a setting_two"
```

It's not straightforward to use the original data. The play below separates the keys and values

```
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_groups: "{{ my_data.keys()}}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }} {{ my_data|dict2items|json_query(my_query)|to_yaml }}"
      loop: "{{ my_groups }}"
      vars:
        my_query: "[?key=='{{ item }}'].value"
```

and gives:

```
"msg": "group_b - - {setting_three: text three}\n  - {setting_four: text four}\n"
"msg": "group_a - - {setting_one: text one}\n  - {setting_two: text two}\n"
```

Multi-step loops are needed to proceed. For example the play below

```
- set_fact:
    my_data1: |
      {% for group, values in my_data.items() %}
      {% for value in values %}
      {% for item_key, item_val in value.items() %}
      Task {{ group }} {{ item_key }},
      {% endfor %}{% endfor %}{% endfor %}
- debug:
    msg: "{{ my_data1.split('\n') }}"
```

gives:

```
"msg": [
    "Task group_b setting_three,", 
    "Task group_b setting_four,", 
    "Task group_a setting_one,", 
    "Task group_a setting_two,", 
    ""
]
```

Comment: The structure is not the same. I have a dict in a dict, not a list in a dict. I wouldn't think that was an uncommon structure.

Comment: It's not an uncommon structure. It's merely inappropriate for this problem.